# How to integrate asp.net web application with Google Drive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api, google-apps

I have existing web application in asp.net, now i like to add Google drive to my web application. Is it possible or not in asp.net web application. If it is possible, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you searched and tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you even bother to look at the drive sdk before asking? Right in the front page of the sdk there is a complete .net sample for drEdit and all apis in help contain a sample in .net as well.

Comment: For those too lazy to search, I mean, for reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet

Comment: i am working in asp.net websit not in asp mvc architecture, i will allow users to use google login in my website, after that they can access their documents and calendars through my website. So i am trying lot, but i couldn't find the solution.

Comment: easiest way is this: https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in though you can also implement it without using google+ and just the user's email signin, see here for complete info https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login. BTW you could have avoided the question HOLD if you explained what you actually wanted (google signin) in your question.